# "com.android.tools.build:gradle" show error: "Remote host terminated the handshake" on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: android, gradle, ros

I am learning [android_core](https://github.com/rosjava/android_core.git) on Ubuntu 18.04 ROS Melodic. My build.gradle can download mysql, but stops download "com.android.tools.build:gradle" and show errors:

```
./gradlew clean

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android_core'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
               > Remote host terminated the handshake

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

The above url can download by `wget https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom`

The build.gradle is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        //classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38'     /*it works*/
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'    /*Remote host terminated the handshake*/
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  
}
```

```
./gradlew clean --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android_core'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
               > Remote host terminated the handshake

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android_core'.
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:73)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$400(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:54)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:107)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:687)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:140)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:60)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:41)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:274)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:182)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:141)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:77)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:154)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:74)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:79)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1054)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1700(DefaultConfiguration.java:123)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.ensureResolved(DefaultConfiguration.java:1489)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.getArtifacts(DefaultConfiguration.java:1461)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.CompositeBuildClassPathInitializer.execute(CompositeBuildClassPathInitializer.java:45)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.CompositeBuildClassPathInitializer.execute(CompositeBuildClassPathInitializer.java:32)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptClassPathResolver.resolveClassPath(DefaultScriptClassPathResolver.java:37)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.getScriptClassPath(DefaultScriptHandler.java:74)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.defineScriptHandlerClassScope(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:204)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:82)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:186)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:66)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:48)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:41)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:105)
        ... 85 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
Required by:
    project :
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.ComponentResolversChain$ComponentMetaDataResolverChain.resolve(ComponentResolversChain.java:94)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.clientmodule.ClientModuleResolver.resolve(ClientModuleResolver.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.ComponentState.resolve(ComponentState.java:208)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.ComponentState.resolve(ComponentState.java:196)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.ComponentState.getMetadata(ComponentState.java:152)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.EdgeState.calculateTargetConfigurations(EdgeState.java:156)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.EdgeState.attachToTargetConfigurations(EdgeState.java:112)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.attachToTargetRevisionsSerially(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:315)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolveEdges(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:202)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:155)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:126)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:123)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:167)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:89)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$5.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:533)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:524)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:509)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1800(DefaultConfiguration.java:123)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getSelectedArtifacts(DefaultConfiguration.java:1037)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.access$3100(DefaultConfiguration.java:971)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.ensureResolved(DefaultConfiguration.java:1483)
        ... 107 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:141)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.process(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.resolve(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:138)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:119)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:92)
        ... 135 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.failure(ResourceExceptions.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.getFailed(ResourceExceptions.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.copyToCache(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:201)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.access$300(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor$1.create(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:89)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor$1.create(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:81)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.ProducerGuard$AdaptiveProducerGuard.guardByKey(ProducerGuard.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.getResource(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:81)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadByCoords(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:133)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadStaticResource(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.parseMetaDataFromArtifact(AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.create(AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.resolveStaticDependency(ExternalResourceResolver.java:244)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.doResolveComponentMetaData(MavenResolver.java:127)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ExternalResourceResolver.java:445)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:378)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:138)
        ... 140 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:80)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:84)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.openResource(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.openResource(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.AccessorBackedExternalResource.withContentIfPresent(AccessorBackedExternalResource.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$11.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:237)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$11.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:229)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:314)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:304)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:100)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.withContentIfPresent(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:229)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.copyToCache(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:199)
        ... 155 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:148)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:126)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:103)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:94)
        ... 171 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
        ... 186 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

My enviroments are:
openjdk "1.8.0"
Gradle 4.10.2

I tried add my company's certificate to cacerts, but does no work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found a painful method: run `build.gradle` in a new folder and download `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0` into gradle cache.
But the following download still failed because this does not solve the root causes.

Answer (score 0):

After one day's work, found the reason in `gradle.properties`:

```
-org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
+org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```